# Type inference lost when destructuring

Tags: typescript, type-inference, destructuring

I'm trying to create a helper function in Typescript 4.1.2 that would return an object with the specified properties initialized to some values, but type inference does not work when I use object destructuring. Any ideas?

```js
export function makeType<TKey extends string, U = { [K in TKey]: string }>(...names: readonly TKey[]): U {
    return {} as any; // this would inititalize the values using the names
}

const k = makeType("id", "name1"); // correct type inferred, k.id is string and k.name is string
const {name, value} = k; // this of course works correctly

const {name1, value1} = makeType("name1", "value1"); // inferred types are any ??

const {name2, value2} = makeType("id", "name2"); // this should be a compile error, since there is no value2 on the result
```

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": 2,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "React",
    "module": "ESNext"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not `makeType<K extends string>(...names: readonly K[]): { [key in K]: string }`? This is simpler than what you currently have, and seems to work as you expect.

Comment: Amazing, please post it as an answer, and I will accept it! Thanks a lot!!